# Set value to each element of array of elements in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In my zend application i have a form that contains an array of elements like that:

```
ini1[0]
ini1[1]
...
```

To get they values i use:

```
$value = $form->ini1->getValue();
echo $value[0];
echo $value[1];
...
```

But i don't know how to set values to each elements of this array.
There's any way?

================================================================================

*Code of element creation*

```
$element['ini1'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('ini1');
$element['ini1']->setAttrib('maxLength', '5')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'horaTurno')
                ->setValue('00:00');
```

*I'm creating a manual form, so in my form.phtml i have a for loop that create 7 elements like this:*

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
        echo $this->form->ini1
            ->setAttrib('name', 'ini1['. $i .']')
            ->setAttrib('id', 'ini1['. $i .']');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a foreach-loop ([**PHP.net: foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) you can iterate over your array and set a value on each item:

```
foreach($value as $item) {
    $item->setValue('yourValue');
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this:
foreach($form->ini1 as $val){
     $ini1->setValue('11:00');
}
it don't works.